# Cómo agregar en un Panel SD un Spinning Wheel Dialog

Tags: genexus

Desde Genexus, cómo podría agregar dentro de los Eventos del objeto Panel SD, un mensaje de espera  ("spinning wheel dialog")?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso puedes usar el [Progress external object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39341,Progress+external+object).

Por ejemplo así:

```
Event 'ShowProgress'
    Composite
        Progress.Title = "Procesando"
        Progress.Description = "Espere unos minutos..."
        Progress.Type = ProgressIndicatorType.Indeterminate
        Progress.Show()

        LongRunningProc()

        Progress.Hide()
   EndComposite
EndEvent
```